# views or controller? symfony mvc

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony1, symfony-1.4

```
<?php foreach ($jobeet_job_list as $jobeet_job): ?>
<tr>
  <td><a href="<?php echo url_for('job/show?id='.$jobeet_job->getId()) ?>"><?php echo $jobeet_job->getId() ?></a></td>

  <td><?php echo $jobeet_job->getCompany() ?></td>

  <td><?php echo $jobeet_job->getIsPublic() ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $jobeet_job->getIsActivated() ?></td>

</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

for example would like add class to TR in depending `IsPublic();`

```
<?php foreach ($jobeet_job_list as $jobeet_job): ?>
<tr class=" <?php if ($jobeet_job->getIsPublic() == 0) { echo "public"; } else {echo "unpublic";})?> ">
 <td> <?php if ($jobeet_job->getIsPublic() == 0) { echo "public"; } else {echo "unpublic";})?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

gives:

```
<tr class="public"> or <tr class="unpublic"> and
 <td> public </td> or <td> unpublic </td>
```

the instruction IF ELSE can be in VIEW? should be in the controller in correct MVC?

Comment: `getIsSomething()`? Now that's a great function name (no idea if your framework requires you to name getters like that). Usually the getter for a boolean value is named `isSomething()`

Comment: It's public when the function returns 0 (== false)? It's generally the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be in view, as view decides which markup needs to be returned. Controller is only to provide data necessary to make the decision (and the data that is going to be shown of course, but not name of CSS class in this one).

Comment: Same applies - if the data that is to be put needs to be retrieved from somewhere [MVP approach], this is also controller's job. But if you only need to put strings like "public"/"not public", this is a view responsibility, as it "knows" what this field means.